# Service in Android : Parcelable ArrayList between service and activity via Notification

Tags: android, service, android-intent, arraylist, parcelable

I send from a Service a notification which contents Parcelable ArrayList.

```
//my service code
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AutoSearchActivity.class);

//In this list, there is 3 elements
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Staff.JSON_ARRAY,staffs);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent , 0);

Notification notification = new Notification(
    R.drawable.toplogo, 
    (String) getResources().getString(R.string.notification),
    System.currentTimeMillis());

String titleNotification = (String) getResources().getString(R.string.notification_title);

String textNotification = (String) getResources().getString(R.string.notification_content);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(mContext, titleNotification,textNotification, pendingIntent);

notification.vibrate = new long[] { 0, 400, 100, 400, 100, 600 };

notificationManager.notify(ID_NOTIFICATION, notification);
```

After cliking on my notification, AutoSearchActivity is executed. I try to catch data and display them, but only old data are displayed. I guess there is a kind of cache system, but I don't know how to delete it.

```
//in my AutoSearchActivity
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

//only 1 element !!!
ArrayList<SiteStaff> listAppInfo = bundle.getParcelableArrayList(Staff.JSON_ARRAY);
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup , Pending Intent is cached, creates a lot of problems. Change your line to 
`PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent , PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);` to force the Pending intent to take the only latest value even if it is fired multiple times.

Comment: Thank you my friend ~ It works ! First time i heard about Pending intent problem ~ thanks !